# How can I scale CloudFoundry applications "down" without the risk of restarting all of them?

Tags: cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

*This is a question regarding the Swisscom Application Cloud.*

I have implemented a strategy to **restart** already deployed CloudFoundry applications **without** using `cf restart APP_NAME`. I wanted to be able to:

- restart running applications without needing access the app manifest and
- avoid them suffering any down-time.

The general concept looks like this:

1. `cf scale APP_NAME -I 2`

   - increasing the instance count of the app from 1 to 2
   - wait for all app instances to be `running`
2. `cf restart-app-instance APP_NAME 0`

   - restart the "old" app instance
   - wait for all app instances to be `running` again
3. `cf scale easyasset-repower-staging -I 1`

   - decrease the instance count of the app back from 2 to 1

This generally works and usually does what I expect it to do. The problem I am having occurs at Stage (3), where **sometimes** instead of just scaling the instance count back, CloudFoundry will also **restart** all (remaining) instances.

I do not understand:

- Why does this happen only sometimes (all apps restart when scaling down)?
- Shouldn't CloudFoundry keep the the remaining instances up and running?
- If `cf scale` is not able to keep perfectly fine running app instances alive - when is it useful?

*Please Note:*
I am well aware of the Bluegreen / Autopilot plugins for zero-down-time deployment of applications in CloudFoundry and I am actually using them for our deployments from our build server, but they require me to provide a manifest (and additional credentials), which in this case I don't have access to (unless I can somehow extract it from a running app via `cf create-app-manifest`?).

**Update 1:**
Looking at the plugins again I found [`bg-restage`](https://github.com/orange-cloudfoundry/cf-plugin-bg-restage), which apparently does approximately what I want, but I have no idea how reliable that one is.

**Update 2:**
I have concluded that it's probably an obscure issue (or bug) in CloudFoundry and that there are no guarantees given by `cf scale` that existing instances are to remain running. As pointed out above, I have since realised that it is indeed very much possible to generate the app manifest on the fly (`cf create-app-manifest`) and even though I couldn't use the `bg-restage` plugin without errors, I reverted back to the `blue-green-deploy` plugin, which I can now hand a freshly generated manifest to avoid this whole `cf scale` exercise.

**Comment Questions:**

> Why do you have the need to restart instances of your application?

We are caching some values from persistent storage *on start-up*. This restart is happening when changes to that data was detected.

> information about the health-check

We are using all types of health checks, depending on which app is to be re-started (`http`, `process` and `port). I have observed this issue only for apps with health check`http`. I also have a`http-endpoint` defined for the health check.

> Are you trying to alter the memory with cf scale as well?

No, I am trying to keep all app configuration the same during this process.

Comment: Why do you have the need to restart instances of your application? Also, can you please add some information about the health-check you're currently using?

Comment: Are you trying to alter the memory with `cf scale` as well? Changing the instance count should require all instances to be restarted, but changing the memory limit will.

Comment: I'm not sure this story is the exact cause, but it might point towards the issue. If the process version changes somehow, that would cause instances to be killed and recreated -> https://www.pivotaltracker.com/story/show/160207350. Changing app instance count shouldn't do that, but there's some notes on the story about other operations which might.

Answer (score 0):

When you have two running instances, the command

```
cf scale <APP> -i 1
```

will kill instance #1 and instance #0 will not be affected.

Comment: Hi `nic` - thanks for the attempt. I'm not sure if I explained my question well enough, but the problem is that: `sometimes instead of just scaling the instance count back, CloudFoundry will also restart all (remaining) instances`. It usually doesn't happen, but every 10th time or so it does exactly that.

Comment: Hi Chris. Is there a way you could provide us with the application logs that you can collect with "cf logs <APP> --recent" just after this "obscure issue" happens? This might be key to understand the cause of this unexpected unwanted behaviour. After all, you might have encountered the issue Daniel is pointing at. Thank you!